# getting exceptions while upgrading poi jars in java for deprecated method

Tags: java, jar, apache-poi

In my project I have recently update poi final jar that is earlier I was using poi-2.5.1-final-20040804.jar and now I have upgraded to recent one that is poi-2.5.1-final-20040804.jar now the one issue that I faces is that my code which refer to the earlier version of poi uses a method from the package package `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel;` named `addMergedRegio`n which was there in earlier version of poi 2.5

```
 public int addMergedRegion(Region region)
  {
    return this.sheet.addMergedRegion(region.getRowFrom(), region.getColumnFrom(), region.getRowTo(), region.getColumnTo());
  }
```

but as I have moved to the new version of poi 3.5 in which this method is deprecated that is it is now as shown below in poi 3.5

```
 /** @deprecated */
  public int addMergedRegion(org.apache.poi.ss.util.Region region)
  {
    return this._sheet.addMergedRegion(region.getRowFrom(), region.getColumnFrom(), region.getRowTo(), region.getColumnTo());
  }
```

now because of this I am getting run time exceptions as his method is not found since I have started using poi 3.5 , now please advise how can I overcome from this issue as I want my code to work perfectly shall I use any annotation where the method call is happening .

folks any early help would be appreciated .can I add annotation `@SuppressWarnings` to it

Comment: Show the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: the stack trace simply shows that they are not able to find the method named addMergedRegion

Comment: The latest version of Apache POI is not 3.5, it's 3.13! What happens if you try with the very latest version?

Comment: @Gagravarr well agree with you but the issue is that why the conflict is there as i am getting the runtime exception

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the error you get together with your pom.xml if using maven. I have looked at the source for the latest verison of POI (3.9) and the deprecated method still exists: I fail to see then how you can be getting a runtime exception as a result of this.

Comment: Did you recompile your code against the newer POI jars? POI tries to be binary compatible against backwards versions, but sometimes has to fall back to only source compatible

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to the the method in class HSSFSheet.
It has been marked as deprecated in version 3.5 and then completely removed later on (in one of the subsequent versions).

Are you sure that you use the 3.5 version and not a later one (or even the latest ?). If you use maven and don't specify a version, it uses the latest, in which this method has been totally removed, which would give you your stacktrace.
The runtime exception can arise because you compile with a 3.5 version but the one used on your server is a different one...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I agree with you but I have some legacy code which is using this method plus I want to add some extra functionality that is available in 3.5 only so is there any mid way we can find in which we can reach to the solution without any issues further.

Comment: 3.5 would suit your needs, but since the problem you report, I think it's possible that your deployment uses a later version than 3.5. Can you make sure that the 3.5 is the one your deployed code uses ?